# Find a value in XML and access its siblings from the same parent group

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I have an XML file with parent node `hospitalStore` and a few child nodes I need to process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Hospital Store -->
<hospitalStore><!-- Hospital Config -->
    <src><!--Search Path For Files To Move-->
        <path>C:\Users\Desktop\move\*.pdf</path>
    </src>
    <hospital>
        <criteria>Beth Israel requirements</criteria>
        <name>Beth Israel</name>
        <category>OPBEIH</category>
        <destination>C:\Users\Desktop\dest\1\</destination>
        <hospcode>1101</hospcode>
    </hospital><!-- End Hospital Config --><!-- Hospital Config -->
    <hospital>
        <criteria>Beth Israel CCC - WEST requirements</criteria>
        <name>Beth Israel CCC WEST</name>
        <category>OPBICC</category>
        <destination>C:\Users\Desktop\dest\2\</destination>
        <hospcode>1107</hospcode>
    </hospital><!-- End Hospital Config --><!-- Hospital Config -->
    <hospital>
        <criteria>Beth Israel KHD requirements</criteria>
        <name>Beth Israel KHD</name>
        <category>OPBIKD</category>
        <destination>C:\Users\Desktop\dest\3\</destination>
        <hospcode>1102</hospcode>
    </hospital><!-- End Hospital Config --><!-- Hospital Config -->
    <hospital>
        <criteria>Beth Israel KHD requirements</criteria>
        <name>Beth Israel KHD</name>
        <category>OPBIKE</category>
        <destination>C:\Users\Desktop\dest\3\</destination>
        <hospcode>1102</hospcode>
    </hospital><!-- End Hospital Config -->
</hospitalStore><!-- End Hospital Store -->
```

So far my code retrieves the files in a directory and then matches the `basename`'s first 6 characters to the XML child node `category`.

I want to be able to point the file that matches the value in XML `category` to XML `destination` etc and then test destination with a few other functions. I'm unsure how to associate the file with that group of nodes.

```
$cPath="C:\move\outpatient.xml"
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($cPath)
$hName = $xml.hospitalstore.hospital
$src = $xml.hospitalstore.src.path
$fileList= get-childitem -path $src -File

ForEach ($file in $fileList ){

$category = ($file.BaseName.Substring(0,6))
$fileName = $fileList.Name


if ($category -in $hName.category){


$file.Name
$hName.category

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a `hospital` that has a child node `category` matching the condition:

- PowerShell 4+:

  ```
  $hospital = $hospitals.Where({ $_.category -eq $foo }, 'first')[0]
  ```
- PowerShell 3+:

  ```
  $hospital = $hospitals | Where category -eq $foo
  ```

  Aliases: `Where` = `Where-Object` = `?`
- PowerShell 1+:

  ```
  $hospital = $hospitals | Where { $_.category -eq $foo }
  ```

  Aliases: `Where` = `Where-Object` = `?`
- XPath (available in all PS versions for Windows, but not yet in PowerShell for Linux AFAIK):

  ```
  $hospital = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//hospital[category='$foo']")
  ```

The PowerShell 1,2,3 methods return an array of all matching nodes, or a single matching value (not an array), or nothing, iterating the entire array. PowerShell 4 method and SelectSingleNode stop on the first match.

So the boilerplate code could be something like this:

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load('C:\move\outpatient.xml')

$hospitals = $xml.hospitalStore.hospital

Get-ChildItem $src -File | ForEach {
    $file = $_
    $fileCategory = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,6)
    $fileName = $file.Name

    $hospital = $hospitals | Where { $_.category -eq $fileCategory }
    if (!$hospital) {
        Write-Error "$fileCategory not found in XML"
        return # return because we're inside a function-like ScriptBlock
    }
    # use the values
    echo $hospital.criteria
    echo $hospital.name
    echo $hospital.destination
    echo $hospital.hospcode
    echo ''
}
```